# Why does my iterator remove() method not remove anything?

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, iterator

I am trying to use the iterators standard remove method to remove the smallest item in my array.  I am doing this by implementing an iterator to find the smallest item, and then a second iterator to remove it.  My code is below.

```
public Comparable removeMin() {

    Iterator<T> it = iterator();
    T min;
    T next;


    if (it.hasNext()){
        min = it.next();
    } else {
        min = null;
    }

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        next = it.next();
        if (min.compareTo(next) > 0) {
        min = next;
        }
    }

    Iterator<T> it2 = iterator();
    it2 = iterator();
    while (it2.hasNext()) {
        next = it2.next();
        if (min.compareTo(next) == 0) {
            it2.remove();
            break;
        }
    }

    return min;

}
```

Here is the code is main.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Bag<String> sbag = new Bag<String>();
    System.out.println(sbag.size()); // 0

    sbag.add("a");
    sbag.add("b"); 
    sbag.add("c");
    sbag.add("d");
    sbag.add("e");

    sbag.removeMin();

    Iterator<String> it2 = sbag.iterator();
    while (it2.hasNext()) {
        String val = it2.next();
        System.out.println(val);

    }
}
```

When I run that code in main, I expect to get `b, c, d, e` since `a` should have been removed.  Instead, I get `a, b, c, d, e`.  This indicates the removeMin() method is not working properly.  I think the malfunction is in the second while loop with the `it2.remove()` command, but I do not know what I have done wrong.

Can anybody please tell me how to fix my code so that the `it2.remove();` command removes the min item?

Comment: What does `iterator()` do?

Comment: I second PM. Your  code seems to be fine (except you are calling iterator twice for `it2`, which however should not cause any malfunction), in which case your `iterator()` implementation might have problems.

Comment: @SayemAhmed, but if I print min and next right before the `it2.remove()` call, they both print a which is what I expect.  Its just the remove is not working.  Is that still a signifier of fault `iterator()` implementation?

Comment: Looks like a problem with `Bag.remove()` method, not your `removeMin()` method. Or it could be a broken `compareTo()` method I guess; where `x.compareTo(x)` is not zero.

Comment: You should check whether the code even reaches `it2.remove();`. Add a System.out.println line that prints the current value for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using a for-loop instead of an iterator.  My code is below.

```
public Comparable removeMin() {
  Iterator<T> it = iterator();
    T min;
    T next;


    if (it.hasNext()){
        min = it.next();
    } else {
        min = null;
    }


    while (it.hasNext()) {
        next = it.next();
        if (min.compareTo(next) > 0) {
        min = next;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    if (data[i] == min) {
        data[i] = null;

        for (int j = i+1; j < data.length; j++) {
            data[j-1] = data[j];
        }

      }

    }

    size--;
    return min;

}
```

Comment: If you are using Java 8, you might want to look into using a stream to filter this collection. You could replace most of this brittle, imperative code with a few lines.